# Entity Framework: Implement interface when generating from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I'm having a few tables on SQL Server, which have similar structure - int Id and string Value. 
This tables linked to main table via foreign key, so I'm wrote a bit of logic for mapping a string values to id's in models in MVC Razor. This feature requires that models used as dictionary implement simple IKeyValue interface with Id and Value, but after updating model from database I can loose interface implementation from models and must write it again. 
Any way to automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you modifying the auto-generated file? If so, you should not do this, for the exact reason you describe in your question -- it will get overwritten.

All of the classes in the generated file should be `partial`. You can take advantage of this by creating another class (in a different file, but in the same project), make sure it has the same declaration (and namespace), and have it implement the interface. This way the class will implement the interface, but will not be overwritten the next time you refresh the schema from the database.